# Technical Firmware Development Questions about USB

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope, off-topic

Where do you ask questions about USB ? For that matter, is Stack OverFlow the appropriate place to do this ? Is there a USB area on StackExchange ?

I'm going to have a lot of USB questions for the next several days. These will be technical questions; e.g., protocol, signaling, propagation, wake-up, suspend, Unit ID assignment, On-The-Go, and these sorts of topics.

In many cases, I will not have previously written Source code. In all cases, I will have a clearly defined question; e.g., a stream of bytes from the source to the destination, packet construction, and so on.

Comment: Are they specifically about writing code to access USB? (Firmware code is still code, IMO)

Comment: @AndrewBarber   They will be more about clarifying the packet construction and the protocol itself. USB has a lot of rules. I'm frequently wondering what they actually mean

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes, I'm going to be implementing USB in firmware for and embedded device

Answer (score 4):

For writing firmware and interfacing with the USB standard, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is the place!

For writing code on computer side, stack overflow is probably a better choice, but you can ask questions on EE as related to this also, the more into computer programming you become the more you leave EE and enter SO, but the boundary, as is normal, is somewhat fuzzy here.

Comment: OP can take a survey of the audience (by checking the existing question) on the 2 sites, so that he/she can gauge which site is better to ask the question on. (After considering how on topic the question is)

Comment: @nhahtdh Would that be cross-posting a question ? I thought that's a bad thing in the Stack Exchange Empire.

Comment: @User.1: I don't suggest to cross-post (post in 2 places). Just checking which site has better chance of your question being answered, and post on that site.

Comment: @nhahtdh Aha, sensible, see which one has more questions about USB protocol details and all, huh ?

Comment: @User.1: Basically, yes. 1) Search for similar question whether it helps you or not 2) Even if it does not help, you know roughly whether you will get some answer or not 3) Post your question on the better site (make sure it is on topic or at least not closed as off-topic at sight, though).

Comment: @nhahtdh the problem with comparing any site to [so] will be that it is so easy for SO to have more questions related to it over the years.